# Remote Debugging Chrome on Galaxy Nexus

Tags: google-chrome, remote-debugging, galaxy-nexus

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging

I followed the steps but I did't get the prompt on my galaxy nexus in the step 3 and chrome://inspect/#devices didn't show the phone whereas I've got the prompt and debugged successfully using a nexus 5. I have installed the driver for the galaxy nexus downloaded at Samsung. Previously I could debug with the adb plugin but recently chrome has disabled it and forced me using the native one.

Does anyone know how I can get rid of this issue?

Comment: I'm in the exact same situation. Any resolution to this?

Comment: While changing the driver seemed to work for @user3204729, the solution that worked for me was to run `adb devices` on my PC. [Details here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23928683/450668).

Answer (score 3):

I finally get rid of the unhelpful samsung official driver by 
http://adbdriver.com/downloads/
Please uninstall the original one before install this driver.
Cheers.

Comment: Thank you, I never would have figured out the almost completely working driver from Samsung was preventing me from using the Chrome Debugger.

Comment: This also worked for me on my Galaxy S5. Samsung drivers just did not do the job